# How to query database data with Doctrine and Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a line like this

```
 // $repository is my repository for location data
 $locationObject = $repository->findOneBy(array('name' => $locationName));
```

Which selects the first record it can find from the `Locations` table. Which is fair enough.

However, I have some additional data in that table to make the query more precise. Specifically, an "item_name" column. In the Location class it is specified as such:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Item", inversedBy="locations", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="item_id", referencedColumnName="item_id", onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
protected $item;
```

So there is also an Item table with item_id, item_name, etc.

What I want to do is change the original `findOneBy()` to also filter by item name. So I want something like:

```
 $locationObject = $repository->findOneBy(array('name' => $locationName, 'item' => $itemName));
```

But because `$item` is an object in the Locations class rather than a string or an ID obviously that wouldn't work. So really I want to somehow much against item->getName()...

I'm not sure how I can do this. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you must create a custom query with join. It's better you create a custom repository class for this entity and then creates a custom query build inside it.

Entity:

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Foo.php

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\FooRepository")
 */
 class Foo 
 {
    ...
 }
```

Your repository:

```
 // src/AppBundle/Repository/FooRepository.php

 use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

 class FooRepository  extends EntityRepository  
 {
    public function findByYouWant($id)
    {
       // your query build
    }
 }
```

Controller:

```
 // src/AppBundle/Controller/FooController.php

 use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

 class FooController extends Controller
 {
     public function showAction() 
     {
        // ... your code
        $locationObject = $repository->findByYouWant($id);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add a method to your Location repository class, and create a query similiar to the one below:

```
class LocationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findLocationByItemName($locationName, $itemName)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('location');
        $qb->select('location')
            ->innerJoin(
                'MyBundle:Item',
                'item',
                Query\Expr\Join::WITH,
                $qb->expr()->eq('location.item', 'item.item_id')
            )
            ->where($qb->expr()->like('location.name', ':locationName'))
            ->andWhere($qb->expr()->like('item.name', ':itemName'))
            ->setParameter('locationName', $locationName)
            ->setParameter('itemName', $itemName);
        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a custom dql.You can construct it using the querybuilder.

```
//in your controller
protected function getEntities($itemName){
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
    $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb->select('a')->from('YourBundleAlias:YourEntityName', 'a')->join('a.item','b')->where('b.item = :item')->setParameter('item', $itemName);
    return $qb->getQuery()->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as easy as:

```
$locationObject = $repository->findOneBy(array(
    'name' => $locationName, 
    'item' => $itemObject
));
```

Using Doctrine2 in order to do a findBy on a related entity field you must supply an entity instance: `$itemObject`.